# Prevent multiple rows added dynamically on editing new inserted row in DGV vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I'm binding `dataset` to `datagridview` using `Flx.DataSource = New DataView(ds.Tables("ConumptionInventTransTbl"))` which in result looks like this.

[image]

when i start entering values in this row all sudden some times multiple rows added like this on reaching third or fourth column .

[image] Some times it works fine with no extra row addition. But mostly, i'm facing extra row addition in grid. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you still get it if you remove the DataView

Comment: Is it each time you add a row - it's adding another row somehow?  It may not be in the code you posted - do you have something in the Row_Add* events?

Comment: It shouldn't matter but do you really need to create that `DataView` at all? What is it achieving? As for the issue, there's no way that that happens on its own. Either you have written the code that does that or your system is broken.

Comment: Through dataview data binding become faster than regular binding

Comment: @CaiusJard no i dont't get this when dataview is removed....

Comment: *dataview data binding become faster* - do you say this because you know it or because someone told you it?

Comment: I've experienced this while loading hundreds of rows in bind to grid through looping is slower operation....

Comment: @CaiusJard you canclear this if I'm wrong here too...

Comment: I don't typically use dataviews; all my work is with strongly typed datatables bound through `BindingSource`s but they likely amount to the same thing.  You can improve loading performance in a variety of ways with data bound items, the most effective being to call "begin/end load data" on your table or set, set "enforce constraints" to false on your set, turn off "raise list changed events" on a binding source while you're loading the data.. don't load more data than you need, and code things so big result sets are returned from the db, possibly by joining tables into your queries

Comment: For example, if you load Customer by customer id, then load orders by customer id, don't then loop the orders loading 100 products by 100 queries for a single  product; do a join from products to orders so you can get all products via one customer id - `SELECT p.* FROM products p INNER JOIN orders o ON o.productid = p.id WHERE o.customerid = @c` => load X thousand products by customer ID rather than looping 100 orders loading X thousand products one by one

Comment: ps; loading hundred of rows to a grid by binding shouldn't involve ANY looping. Post more code; it might well turn out you're "doing it wrong"

Comment: actually we are using [this](https://imgur.com/CF9u3eP) technique normally which makes grid loading slower in some cases....

Comment: @CaiusJard is there any solution of problem that i'm facing....?

Comment: Yikes! That's horrendous - was writing that code used as punishment for a developer who did something wrong? It's like writing same lines over and over in school detention! :)

Comment: @CaiusJard Alas! that was my senior work.

Comment: I think they might be "old school VB6" programmer then...

Comment: exactly with no doubt

Comment: @CaiusJard then how to map dataset value to dgv columns? because dgv columns made statically...

Answer (score 0):

Here I load one hundred thousand random strings into a datatable and show them in a grid with alternating row styles, in about a second:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private st As DateTime
    Private afterLoad As DateTime
    Private afterBind As DateTime

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        st = DateTime.Now

        Dim dt As New DataTable
        dt.BeginLoadData()
        dt.Columns.Add("a")
        dt.Columns.Add("b")
        For i = 0 To 100000 Step 1
            dt.Rows.Add(Guid.NewGuid.ToString(), Guid.NewGuid.ToString())
        Next

        afterLoad = DateTime.Now

        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dt

        afterBind = DateTime.Now

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        MessageBox.Show("Load dt took " & (afterLoad - st).TotalSeconds & "s and bind took " & (afterBind - afterLoad).TotalSeconds & "s")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UspsE.png]

I suggest you start simple, using this as a model, and work back towards what you have there

Comment: then how to map dataset value to dgv columns?

Comment: DataSets don't have values; they're a collection of DataTable objects. DataTables have DataColumn and DataRow. If you bind a datatable to a datagridview with `dgv.DataSource = dt` and `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true` then the dgv will auto create columns based on the properties of the DataColumn objects in the datatable. You can see this in my example - my table has columns called "a" and "b" added by `dt.Columns.Add()` - the grid just finds these and uses them as columns titled "a" and "b" (in the picture). You don't have to use autogenerate; you can build the dgv columns collection yourself

Comment: or you can use autogenerate and then modify the generated columns (or add/remove them too) after, or you can just name your datatable columns as how you want the grid to look and use autogenerate all the way. Personally, I don't have any of these problems; I use strongly typed DataSets all the time, so I know exactly what columns are in my tables, and when I drag the tables out of the datasources window and drop them on the form designer, it makes a datagridview with all the columns, then I edit them at design time. Here's an example of how i might work with a DB https://youtu.be/zrtjZlTYLQA

Comment: actually i was filling dataset through ado connection like `DatasetFill(SQL, "PurchaseInvoiceTbl")` and then bind to dgv

Comment: **DataSets don't contain data**. DataSets contain DataTables. DataTables contain DataRows, DataRows contain data. You might have coded some custom `DatasetFill` method that takes an sql and a table name, but it doesn't fill a dataset, it fills a datatable (which may or may not be inside a dataset). You don't bind a dataset to a grid, you bind a datatable. As a name "DatasetFill" may also be wrong because "Fill" implies "fill this thing I'm giving you" but your method doesnt take a DataSet param; an important difference when you work with eg DataAdapter- has a `Fill()`, fills an existing thing